# Radar Chart flutter ( multi_charts)

Tags: flutter, charts, radar-chart

How to add Line with circle point on the top of radar chart ( with the packages Multi_charts) like the pic below ;

[image]

I could do this : ( im asking for how to make gradient color inside the GraphData )

[image]

Comment: Have you find any solution for this ?